# Accessing Slate application Logs (Hits, metrics, user retention rate)

Tags: google-analytics, palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I am wondering if there are ways to see how many people in your organization are accessing your Slate or workshop application? On conventional websites this can be achieved by google analytics, I wonder if there something like Google Analytics can be implemented here as well?

My colleagues have tried implementing Google Analytics inside Slate but it did not work out. My intuition is that there should be a way to log these metrics.

Answer (score 0):

For Slate, you can contact your Foundry Support team about enabling the Slate usage metrics feature, which captures aggregated usage and performance metrics from your app.

Workshop does not yet have automatic usage or performance metrics.

In either Slate or Workshop, you can use Actions and create your own interaction metrics to capture information about usage, though you should check with your platform adminstrator and/or infosec team to ensure you're complying with relevant privacy regulations and company policy before capturing any granular user interaction data.